# Update HTML content partially with Express server side

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

On my website need to load some JSON files and generally, I would use `fetch` on the **client side** like so:

```
fetch(jsonFileLocation)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    document.getElementById("jsonOutput").innerText = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
  });
```

But in my case, there's a significant delay in the HTML rendering, users would see a blank space first, then the JSON content loaded up. So I figured if I render the JSON content **server side**, it may speed things up a bit.

I could parse the JSON first then `res.render()` the HTML entirely, but I don't want the process of parsing the JSON file to *delay* the rest of the page, so in my Node/Express/Pug setup I tried to do two renders:

```
res.render('index', {
  title: 'Homepage',
  mainContent: '...'
});

fs.readFile(jsonFileLocation, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) { 
    return;
  }
  res.render('index', {
    jsonOutput: JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)
  })
})
```

But this gives me an error of `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`.

What is a better approach to this problem?

Comment: You should figure out what exactly is slow first; it's not likely that the delay is caused by in-browser rendering. If your server code is the source of the delay, then doing more work on the server will just make things slower. Gather actual performance data so that you're not working in the dark.

Comment: Great points and I will look into the cause for slowness, but to my question, are there any ways of partially rendering HTML content from the server side like I tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a pug (or node/express) issue, it's the way that HTTP works - one request has one response.  Sending a second response violates this principle.

I'd suggest loading the JSON file on the server straight into a JavaScript variable in the pug template, then having the client do all the parsing work on it.

Route:

```
res.render('index', {
  title: 'Homepage',
  mainContent: '...',
  jsonOutput: JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)
});
```

Inside your pug template:

```
script.
  var jsonOutput = !{jsonOutput || []};
```

If you are accessing the same files over and over again then you could also store them in a variable at the top of your route so it's persisted in memory.  You could alternatively use a plugin line node-cache to do this with some more options, or even use redis cache to host the JSON content.